# using jquery in joomla

Tags: jquery, joomla

I am trying to use a simple thickbox as in here:
http://twostepmove.com/modules/mod_form/tmpl/demo/main_form.php

but when putting the same exact code in a joomla module the link doesn't respond at all.
the code is:

```
<a href="#TB_inline?height=155&width=400&inlineId=modalWindow" class="thickbox">Click here    
for an autocomplete inside a thickbox window.</a> (this should work even if it is beyond   
the fold)
<div id="modalWindow" style="display: none;">
            <p>
...
            </p>
    </div>
```

and as I said it doesn't work at all when put inside a joomla module.
should I install some sort of plugin or something like that? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of jQuery plugins for Joomla, or you can place jQuery script in the index.php file manually. Be careful not to mix with other javascript frameworks, you can get a conflict

Comment: what the plugins actually do? and how to look for the correct one?

Comment: Go here and pick any of jquery plugins, they all will work: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/advanced-search-results/261594 if you use Firefox and have firebug installed, you can get firequery extension, it will tell you which version of Jquery is installed in your website http://firequery.binaryage.com/

Answer (score 1):

Is there are reason you don't want to use the built in lightbox? You can add class="modal" to a link and the built in lightbox work without any extensions.

Comment: Just add class="modal" to an anchor tag.

Comment: i tried something like:
    <a href="http://www.google.com" class="modal">google</a>
but it works as ordinary link. don't have to install some plugin first?

Comment: You have an extra ; - it should look like <a href="google.com" class="modal">google</a>. Joomla adds the jscript link by default, so you need to make sure your template is not removing it. Look at the source code of any page and look for <script type="text/javascript" src="/media/system/js/modal.js"></script> in the head.

Comment: thanks. any page where? all the pages of the template should have this line?

Comment: The script call should show up on every page in the head. It's added by Joomla automatically unless you have something else suppressing it.

Comment: "something else suppressing it" could also be making a new template instead of the original one (i.e. beez20)..